# multiple values same name sent to req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a shopping website, so my problem is with updating the cart.
Here's the EJS section:

```
<% for (i=0;i<product.length;i++) { %>
<form action="/update-cart" method="POST" id="update-cart">
   <input type="text" name="quantity"  value="<%= products[product[i].pid] %>" title="Qty"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<%= product[i].pid %>">
</form>
<%}%>
<input type="submit" form="update-cart" value="Update Cart">
```

So obviously there's 1 submit button for all the fields, therefore in the server-side, when I do `req.body.pid`, it's grabbing the first pid (which is 1) and returning only 1 and not the other fields. Is it possible to get an array of pid-s from the input field without ajax? Thank you.

Comment: can you show how you are having your `pid` in the form ? The above example shows only one pid being sent.

Comment: This is a small snippet of the code, pid is from the database. I'll edit anyway to clarify.

Comment: `Is it possible to get an array of pid-s from the input field without ajax?` So how are you submitting the form ? since its not inside the `form` what is the way you are using to submit ?

Comment: `form="update-cart"` in the submit input, `id="update-cart"` in the form. This would allow you to use submit input outside the form.

Comment: huh..!! How can you place multiple form with same `id` ? Won't the submit always pick up only one of the form and the rest will be ignored ?

Comment: You're right but I can't have more than 1 submit button. I'm super-confused, I think this has to be done through ajax.

Comment: if you are generating the form as shown above(sequentially with nothing else in between) then there is no need of multiple forms. If you are generating the forms at diff places based on your page structure, then you need help of `ajax`.

Comment: I do need multiple forms, each form is designated to each product. You're right, I do need ajax. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No sure i've understood correctly, you have only one `pid` input.

If you need multiple you can use the array notation in the name, something like `pid[]`

```
<form action="/update-cart" method="POST" id="update-cart">
   <input type="text" name="quantity"  value="<%= products[product[i].pid] %>" title="Qty"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="pid[]" value="<%= product[i].pid %>">
   <input type="hidden" name="pid[]" value="<%= product[i+1].pid %>">
   <input type="submit" form="update-cart" value="Update Cart">
</form>
```

Pay attention to the fact that i've putted the submit button inside the form, so you will get the native submit behaviour.

Comment: I can't use the submit button inside the form, it has to be outside so that it targets all the products at once.

Comment: also, after googling and checking stackoverflow, I did realize we need to use [] next to the name, but what about the server-side ? req.body. what ?